# SortofSorting on Open.Kattis.com fails on the second test case despite running on every test case I have generated.

Tags: java, stable-sort

I am fairly new to Java programming although I have been programming in other languages for a few years now. I have recently begun tackling different programs on Kattis to assign to my students. I would like to develop solution manuals prior to assigning the problems. (I do recognize that they may find this post. Please only guide me to the answer without providing the solution!). A link to the problem is below:

https://open.kattis.com/problems/sortofsorting

I have programmed the stable sort to meet the criteria of the problem. I want to make the solution for students as simple as possible without using built in functions. I have discussed the solution with colleagues but no one has been able to discover the corner case/issue that prevents the code from generating the correct output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sorted {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in); //User_input takes in input
        int names = user_input.nextInt(); //names is the number of names that are coming
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //list is the list of names
        String name; //name is the current name
        int minimumIndex; //minimum index is the index of the current lowest character count
        int ascii1; //ascii value of the minimum index
        int ascii2; //ascii value of the current index
        String temp; //used to swap names in the list
        boolean first = true; //used to only print newline after each case (was used as an attempt to fix Kattis solution but not needed)
        while (names!=0) //while lists exist
        {
            if (first == false)
            {
                System.out.println(); //print blank line after each case
            }
            for(int counter = 0;counter<names;counter++)
            {
                //take in each name - done
                name = user_input.next();
                list.add(name);
            }

            //sort the names using selection sort
            for(int j = 0; j<names-1;j++)
            {
                minimumIndex = j;
                for(int i=j+1;i<names;i++)
                {
                    ascii1 = (int) list.get(minimumIndex).charAt(0);
                    ascii2 = (int) list.get(i).charAt(0);

                    if(ascii2 < ascii1) //sorting by first character
                    {
                        minimumIndex = i;
                    }
                    if(ascii1 == ascii2) //sorting by second character
                    {
                        ascii1 = (int) list.get(minimumIndex).charAt(1);
                        ascii2 = (int) list.get(i).charAt(1);
                        if(ascii2 < ascii1)
                        {
                            minimumIndex = i;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (minimumIndex != j) //if not already smallest element, swap elements
                {
                    //perform a swap here
                    temp = list.get(j);
                    list.set(j,list.get(minimumIndex));
                    list.set(minimumIndex, temp);
                }
            }

            //output the names
            for(int counter = 0;counter<names;counter++)
            {
                System.out.println(list.get(counter));
            }
            //clear the list of elements        
            for(int counter=names-1;counter>=0;counter--)
            {
                list.remove(counter);
            }
            //get next case         
            names = user_input.nextInt();
            if (first == true)
            {
                first = false; //again, used for spacing for Kattis.
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("complete");
        //System.out.println();
        //user_input.close();
    }
}
```

I have tried sorting differently thinking that my interpretation of the problem was incorrect, including sorting all in alphabetical order then sorting by ascii order, but this also yielded an incorrect answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What input does it fail for?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your sort. Replacing it with `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.substring(0, 2)));` makes the tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort is not stable. It will fail with this input, for example:

```
3
px1
px2
pa
0
```

The simplest fix would be to move the element at `minimumIndex` rather than swapping it with the element at `j`.

Instead of:

```
if (minimumIndex != j) //if not already smallest element, swap elements
{
    //perform a swap here
    temp = list.get(j);
    list.set(j,list.get(minimumIndex));
    list.set(minimumIndex, temp);
}
```

Try:

```
if (minimumIndex != j)
{
    list.add(j, list.remove(minimumIndex));
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying now. It was so difficult to notice such a small detail before. I have made the change and ran it, but it still fails. I am hoping to troubleshoot more early next week!

Comment: I've tested this change on kattis. I submitted the code in your question with only the change above, and it passed.